# Use index of one array to extract value from list to be appended into new array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, indexing

If I have one `numpy` array that contains a set of indices, how would I apply those indices to a list of data, which in turn will extract the corresponding data values and append these into a new `numpy` array?

The code I tried to use was this:

```
second_index = np.zeros(len(first_index))

for i in range(len(first_index)):
    second_index[i] = data[first_index[i]]
print(second_index)
```

Both `first_index` and `second_index` are 1D `numpy` arrays, and I would expect to see the same number of elements in both `first_index` and `second_index`. However, I receieve the following error message

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

Should I be using nested `for-loops` instead and perform the loop over two different ranges?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you provide data and expected outcome.?

Comment: So the data list looks like this: 
```data = [0.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]```. 
The first index looks like:
```first_index = [7,17]```. 

So at the moment the expected outcome of the final index should be:

```second_index = [7,17]```. 

As you can see this is because the 7th and 17th elements of the data index are 7 and 17, respectively, so, whilst this may initially seem trivial to use the first index, I'd like to be able to use the second_index in the case that the data array changes.
Hope this explanation was ok? Thanks

Comment: Let me know if that answer helps..your query is bit confusing so I'll refine data accirdingly

Comment: To clarify, if the data was ```data = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36]``` instead, and given that the ```first_index = [7,17]```, then the result I hope to get is ```second_index = [14,34]```. Hope that makes things a bit clearer?

Comment: In that case, it would be `[16, 36]`, not `[14, 34]`.

Comment: @swag2198 yeah that's correct, thanks very much for your suggestion below - it works out fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly index using `numpy` arrays:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.array([2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36])
>>> first_index = np.array([7, 17])
>>> second_index = data[first_index]
>>> second_index
array([16, 36])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ex= [0.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
newarr=[]
for i in range(len(ex)):
    newarr.append(ex[i])
print(newarr) 

[0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Is this you looking for..?

Comment: Err not quite, think this would just append all the values from one array to another? I'm trying to use an array to retreieve values from a dataset by indexing the dataset with the elements of the first array. Then I'd like to append those retrieved values to a new array. Thanks anyway though!